# How to enable the GridView Delete Button only for certain rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView with `AutoGenerateEditButton` enabled and upon clicking the Edit button, it brings up the usual "Update" and "Cancel". I need to add a Delete button only for certain rows. I figured this would go in the `Gridview1_RowDataBound` function, but I want to know if this is even possible.

For example, I click on Row 13 (a row I don't want the "Delete" button) and it only gives me the option of "Update" and "Cancel".

I then click on Row 17 (a row I do want the "Delete" button) and it gives me "Update", "Cancel", and "Delete".

Or is there a better way to "delete" a row?

Comment: Yes you are correct, you can control this through the RowDataBound event. If your creating custom controls remember they need to be recreated on postback otherwise their events will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.
If you use `AutoGenerateEditButton` you can get the button in `RowDataBound` event.
You can also create your `TemplateField` with the `Button` and set the `Visible` property based on conditions.